# Serve static files with or without extension in restify

Tags: node.js, restify

I need serve both http://localhost/users/list and http://localhost/users/list.html

```
server.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
    directory: './public',
}));
```

This code only works if you specify the .html extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static) which is middleware for [expressjs](https://github.com/expressjs/express) and [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) and it worked.

```
var restify = require('restify');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

server = restify.createServer(options);

server.use(restify.acceptParser(server.acceptable));
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());
server.use(serveStatic('./public', { extensions: ['html'] }));

server.get(/.*/, restify.serveStatic({
    directory: './public',
    default: 'index.html',
}));

server.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('Server is running...')
});
```